# Can I keep my last name if I get married?

Tags: new-york-state, marriage, civil-law

Can I keep my last name the same if I get married? I don't want to hyphenate it either. Is this possible? Is it a **MUST** that I change or hyphenate it?

I am in New York City, New York.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can keep your name; this is the default. [Source:](http://www.cityclerk.nyc.gov/html/marriage/name_change.shtml)

> - Your surname does not change automatically upon marriage unless you elect to change it.
> - Nothing in the law requires you to change your name when getting married; it is your personal choice.
> - You are not required to have the same surname as your spouse.

Comment: Note that this does allow for changing your surname to something else entirely.  Smith marries Jones and changes surname to Brown and Jones changes surname to Williams.